# Dlookup for date returing Type Mismatch error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I can't quite figure out what is wrong with this code that is causing a "Type Mismatch" error. I have a feeling it has to do with all the ' and " but I try all sorts of combinations and still no luck. I have tried `Dim duedate As String` but no change. Where am I going wrong with this one?

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

Cat1 = Me.Text175.Value
AssetNum1 = Me.Text177.Value

Dim duedate As Date
duedate = FormatDateTime(Nz(DLookup("[Calibration Due Date]", "[Calibration Data]", "[ID] = " & AssetNum1 And "[Category] = " & Cat1), ""), vbShortDate)

If duedate = "" Then
Me.Text26 = "Oopps"
Else
Me.Text26 = duedate
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBlades's answer addresses one issue with your code that needs to be fixed, but there is another reason that you will get type mismatch errors with the posted code.

When the DLookup() in the Nz() evalutes to null, Nz() will pass "" (empty string) as the value to be formatted with FormatDateTime(); [FormatDateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251489%28v=office.14%29.aspx) requires a date expression as its first argument, and an empty string is not a valid date.

Additionally, the following piece of code is not valid:

```
If duedate = "" Then
'stuff
End If
```

because you are attempting to evaluate whether duedate is an empty string. duedate is defined as a date value in your code and cannot be an empty string  (this is likely where the actual error you are encountering is coming from assuming the DLookup() function has not yet returned null).

The Nz() function in your code will need to evaluate to something that FormatDateTime() can understand. As a simple workaround, Nz() could return a value that has no meaning in your database, but can be evaluated as a date; for example 1. One evaluates to 12/31/1899 when formatted as vbShortDate. Your validation block would then be:

```
If duedate = #12/31/1899# Then
    Me.Text26 = "Oopps"
Else
    Me.Text26 = duedate
End If
```

Note that you could use 0, but 0 is both #12/30/1899# AND #12:00:00 AM# (and the IDE will in fact convert #12/30/1899# to #12:00:00 AM# when compiling). #12:00:00 AM# or 0 or #12/30/1899#, though, could potentially have meaning so it's best not to use it as the placeholder value.

**EDIT:**

If AssetNum1 or Cat1 could be null, you can achieve what you want using the following:

```
Dim Cat1 as string
Dim AssetNum1 as Long
Dim duedate As Date

If IsNull(Me.Text175.Value) or IsNull(Me.Text177.Value) Then
    Me.Text26 = "Oopps"
Else
    Cat1 = Me.Text175.Value
    AssetNum1 = Me.Text177.Value
    duedate = FormatDateTime(Nz(DLookup("[Calibration Due Date]","[Calibration Data]","[ID] = " & AssetNum1 & " And [Category] = """ & Cat1 & """"),1),vbShortDate)
    If duedate = #12/31/1899# Then
        Me.Text26 = "Oopps"
    Else
        Me.Text26 = duedate
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This is what's probably causing the actual error, agreed.

Comment: Thanks guys! Combining both your changes, it works perfectly now. I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking. Must have just been having brain farts there :P

Comment: @viking4821  I spoke too soon. So when the dlookup does return null (table had no date value for the specific looup requirements), I get a "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID] = And [Category] = '". Obviously because those fields are null in the lookup so dlookup doesn't like it. How can I eliminate this error when the fields become null and just make my textbox on the report be null?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying. AssetNum1, etc. can't be null if they're part of the Dlookup criteria expression. You're trying to having the function parse [field] = And; it's expecting a number or a string after the equals sign. With respect to fixing this, we need more information about what these values are and why they wouldn't exist in your table.

Comment: The ultimate goal is I am creating a report that is a Certificate of Calibration. I am wanting to grab the latest calibration due date for the instrument used to calibrate the other instrument. So what it is in the table is an asset number (assetnumX), a category (CatX), and the calibration due date, amongst other data. The category is text and the asset number is numerical. The report can handle up to 3 instruments used to calibrate another instrument. So when there is only 1 used, the other 2 will be blank on the report (or null in the dlookup sense).

Comment: So there will be times when dlookup is null. I have tried the below code in order to skip past the dlookup if certain criteria is not met, but for some reason it won't skip and still tries to run dlookup anyway. `If Me.Text214.Value = Null Then GoTo Cont1 Else...` `Me.Text214.Value` is the next text box on the report that would display the next standard used if a second one was even used. Then the dlookup for that one would run if it had a value, and skip the dlookup if it was null. And also, all this code is being ran at the "on load" event for the report.

Comment: Null is not a value, so you can't check if something equals Null; rather, use the IsNull() function, which will return true if the expression evaluated is null, else false. I've posted some more code in the answer that should work when AssetNum1 or Cat1 is null.

Comment: @viking4821 - That got rid of the error, but now when `Me.Text175.Value` or `Me.Text177.Value` does contain a value, the dlookup is not returning a date value (or any value at all) to place into `Me.Text26` on the report. I notice you had removed the `Nz()` and `FormatDateTime()`. Was that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, let me fix that.

Comment: @viking4821 - it is still not placing a value into `Me.Text26`. A date value is in the table, so I know it is not a problem on that end.

Comment: Is a value being assigned to duedate?

Comment: Yes, the correct date is being assigned to duedate when I have it output the result to a msgbox. I have also made sure that the textbox format is set to "short date".

Comment: @viking4821 - also have another dlookup issue. how do I get a dlookup to return a hyperlink and display the hyperlink in a textbox? `VendorYN = DLookup("[VendorCert]", "[Calibration Data]", "[Certificate Number] = " & CertNum & "")` The textbox only returns VendorNY as the hyperlink and not the actual hyperlink that is in the table field. Am I supposed to format the dlookup differently or is it in my `Me.Text12 = "Vendor Certificate Of Calibration#VendorYN#"`? No one else on a google search seems to have asked this question or any answers outside of the MS Excel vlookup function.

Comment: You should create a new stackoverflow question for the hyperlink issue.

Comment: Does control Text26 on the form have a control source set? Or is it bound to field in a table?

Comment: I found a way around it. If I change `If IsNull(Me.Text175.Value) or IsNull(Me.Text177.Value) Then Me.Text26 = "Oopps"` to `If IsNull(Me.Text175.Value) or IsNull(Me.Text177.Value) Then GoTo <name_of_marker>` then it bypasses the dlookup and does not place anything in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have your double quote in the wrong place and need another concatenation operator, it seems.  Assuming Cat1 is numeric:

```
duedate = FormatDateTime(Nz(DLookup("[Calibration Due Date]", "[Calibration Data]", "[ID] = " & AssetNum1 & " And [Category] = " & Cat1), ""), vbShortDate)
```

If Cat1 is text:

```
duedate = FormatDateTime(Nz(DLookup("[Calibration Due Date]", "[Calibration Data]", "[ID] = " & AssetNum1 & " And [Category] = '" & Cat1 & "'"), ""), vbShortDate)
```